# In Contract D, why does calling function bar first call C, then B, and finally A?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

/* Inheritance tree
   A
 /  \
B   C
 \ /
  D
*/

contract A {
    // This is called an event. You can emit events from your function
    // and they are logged into the transaction log.
    // In our case, this will be useful for tracing function calls.
    event Log(string message);

    function foo() public virtual {
        emit Log("A.foo called");
    }

    function bar() public virtual {
        emit Log("A.bar called");
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function foo() public virtual override {
        emit Log("B.foo called");
        A.foo();
    }

    function bar() public virtual override {
        emit Log("B.bar called");
        super.bar();
    }
}

contract C is A {
    function foo() public virtual override {
        emit Log("C.foo called");
        A.foo();
    }

    function bar() public virtual override {
        emit Log("C.bar called");
        super.bar();
    }
}

contract D is B, C {
    // Try:
    // - Call D.foo and check the transaction logs.
    //   Although D inherits A, B and C, it only called C and then A.
    // - Call D.bar and check the transaction logs
    //   D called C, then B, and finally A.
    //   Although super was called twice (by B and C) it only called A once.

    function foo() public override(B, C) {
        super.foo();
    }

    function bar() public override(B, C) {
        super.bar();
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, calling D.bar() first executes C.bar (Immediate parent) which will then call A.bar (Contract Cs parent). Can anyone explain why is Contract B called here?

[Source](https://solidity-by-example.org/super/)

Comment: add the code , noone will click on link

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't fall into the trick of thinking Solidity is an object-oriented language; it is not.

Hierarchy is just a way to tell the compiler where to put functions in the final smart contract. It has its own parsing logic, so if things get too weird, simply get rid of it at all.

Hierarchy capability was introduced to simplify the development. If it creates confusion, like in this case, it's better to avoid it.

When you compile the mentioned contract in fact, what happens is that all the code and functions are merged into a single contract.

While merging the code, if the compiler finds a function with the same signature (name + parameter's type), it overwrites the previous function, and only the last one is preserved.

The order is determined by the `is` keyword: `contract D is B, C` means that the functions of `B` are merged before the functions of `C`.

In this case `C.foo()` *wins* over `B.foo()`, and `B.foo()` does not actually exist in the final contract. This is why the flow is `D.foo() -> C.foo() -> A.foo()`.

On the contrary, if you specify the `super` keyword, the Solidity compiler understands that you want to retain the corresponding parent's functions in the final contract, and then it put those functions in the *reverse* order it reads it `D.bar() -> C.bar() -> B.bar() -> A.bar()`

Also, please note that

> *Although super was called twice (by B and C), it is only called A once.*

Comment: My confusion is that in case of D.foo(), `super` keyword is specified but the event logs are different. Why doesn't using `super` have the same effect here?

Comment: Because `foo()` in `B` and `C` has no `super`. Imagine like this: Solidity reads first contract `B`, and it writes `foo()` function in a _temp file_. Then it reads `C` contract, it sees the same `foo()` function, and it overwrites it function because it does not contain any `super`. Then it reads `D` contract, it finds another `foo()` function but this time it does NOT overwrite the existing function because the called `C.foo()` contain a `super` keyword. So both functions survive in the final contract, and they are called when you can `D.foo()`

Comment: Again, this is not an object-oriented programming language. Hierarchy is used only to tell the compiler how to parse the file to create a final contract. You can write that contract simply by creating the exact final contract you want, without using hierarchy.

Comment: The hierarchy was introduced to simplify the development. If it creates confusion, like in this case, it's better to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
Also, in your first comment, "the called `C.foo()` contain a `super` keyword", didn't you mean `D.foo()`?

Comment: Yes, I meant _`D.foo()` contains a `super` keyword`_ :) Sorry, I cannot fix that comment any more.